# code for scanning ble4.0 with HMsoft10 in nexus 5

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to connect BLE4.0 with HMsoft-10 it's working but some times it's not work in nexus 5 what to do for this?
Please Replay fast
Advance Thanks.
Thanking You...!

My Code

private void scanLeDevice() {
        new Thread() {

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(SCAN_PERIOD);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
    }.start();
}

private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi,
            byte[] scanRecord) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (device != null) {
                    if (mDevices.indexOf(device) == -1)
                        mDevices.add(device);
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

See what happens if you handle the `startScan()` and `stopScan()` commands also on the UiThread. Better make a delay until `stopScan()` with a handler and postdelayed runnable, as in [this codesample](http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/src/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt/DeviceScanActivity.html). But your question was about connection problems, this is about scanning for devices?